# Persisting gensim LSI model in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, gensim

I have a gensim LSI model that I want to persist in MongoDB. Specifically, I want to persist the following:

- Gensim dictionary (id <-> word)
- Gensim corpus
- LSI model
- MatrixSimilarity index

I know that all of these objects can be saved to file, but I can't figure out how I can save these data to a MongoDB (specifically, using pyMongo). From what I've gathered, I don't need anything like GridFS, because the files are relatively small. But in any case, I want to save them all in a single document, and not separately.

Thanks :)

Comment: How small is "relatively small"? Are you confident that it will never exceed the 16MB document size limit?

Comment: One can never be 100% confident, of course, but if that does happen, it'll have other implications for my project and I'll have to consider an overall redesign in any case.

Comment: I was working on a similar setup, and found that it's enough in my case to use pickle and zlib, and store the compressed model into a single document. You may be able to store each part of your model (i.e. dictionary, model, etc.) in separate documents if you find the whole thing can go beyond 16MB. Do you require an example on how to store the binary data in a document?

Comment: In the end that's more or less what I did (without compression). Pickle and bson's Binary function. I'm planning on answering my question with some of the code, but I haven't had time yet.